# Symfony 5 book the fast track: Is redis necessary for installing guestbook

Tags: php, redis, symfony5

I am trying to launch the "guestbook" web app from the "Symfony 5: the fast track" book. I check that all is well installed by taping the following command:
`symfony book:check-requirements`
and all is ok.
But when I launch the local web server and the guestbook web site with:
`symfony open:local`
I got the following error on my web page:
**Cannot find the "redis" extension nor the "predis/predis" package**

Installation of redis is not mentioned in the book.
I am on Mac Os X Mojave.

Any Idea?

Regards

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to:

- install predis/predis package:

```
composer require predis/predis
```

- and update your `.env.local`:

```
REDIS_URL=redis://localhost:usedPort?timeout=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Install redis in your library, you can download and read instruction here [Redis PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.2.1/windows)

Comment: OP  says " I am on Mac Os X Mojave" - your link is for windows.